# A T split using tikz coordinates only having text on either side of the line before the split

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I can't figure out how if I move a T split down to place the text only on the both sides of the line before the T instead of after the split on both lines like shown in the example below. I have shown what I want in red in the photo below the MWE.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}% <-- added for inserting images, had to be before package `tikz`
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% <-- in real document remove option `demo`
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, decorations.pathmorphing,
                positioning, quotes}
\tikzset{
                    every edge quotes/.style = {font=\small, text=black, align=left},% <-- added for writing edge label in more lines
     block/.style = {draw, rounded corners, very thick,
           minimum width=#1, minimum height=2em, inner sep=2.5pt, outer sep=0pt,
           text width =\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
           align=center},
block_dash/.style = {draw, dashed, rounded corners, thin,
            inner sep=1.5pt, minimum size=2em, text=black,
            execute at begin node={\begin{varwidth}{9cm}},
            execute at end node={\end{varwidth}}},
block_noborder/.style = {text width=#1, align=left, % <-- renamed and removed surplus options
            text=black, inner sep=1.5pt},
 connector/.style = {-stealth',very thick},
 snakeline/.style = {decorate,
            decoration={snake, amplitude=.4mm, segment length=1.5mm,
                        pre length=2mm, post length=2mm},
            thick, gray, -stealth'},
              }% end of tikzset

\usepackage{varwidth, mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}% <-- added for correct writing of units

\begin{document}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%scale=0.1,
    auto,
    node distance=15mm and 0mm]
\node (B31) [block=21mm]         {Split this matrix block into two small blocks.};
\node (B32) [block=21mm,
            right=5mm of B31]   {Split this matrix block into two small blocks.};
\path   let \p1 = ($(B31.west)-(B32.east)$),
            \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
        node (B2) [block=\n1,
                   above right=of B31.north west]  {Half}
        node (B1) [block=\n1,
                   above=of B2]   {Gamma}
        node (B4) [block=\n1,%,
         below right=of B31.south west]   {Text here};
%
\draw[connector]    
    ($(B1.north)+(0,1)$) node[left] {$x(n)$} -- (B1)
    (B1) to ["$y^{}_\text{s}$" ', "Something\\ here"]  (B2); 
    \coordinate[below=4mm of B2.south -| B31] (B33); % <-- auxiliary coordinates, for orthogonal paths between `box` nodes
    \coordinate[below=4mm of B2.south -| B32] (B34);% <-- u
    \coordinate[below=4mm of B32.south-|  B4] (B35);
\draw[connector]
        (B2) |- (B33) to ["$y^{}_\text{s}$" ', "Something\\ here"]    (B31);
\draw[connector]
        (B2) |- (B34) to ["$y^{}_\text{s}$" ', "Something   here"]    (B32)
        (B31) edge ["$y^{}_\text{s}$" ', "short\\ text"]    (B31 |- B4.north);
\draw[connector]
        (B32) |- (B35) to ["$y^{}_\text{s}$" ', "Something\\ here"]   (B4);
%
\draw[snakeline]
        (B32.east) -- + (0.7,0) node[block_dash,right] {Text to the left of it here. Text to the left of it here.Text to the left of it here.Text to the left of it here};
\draw[snakeline] % <-- this part of code is rewrite from scratch
        (B1.east) -- + (0.7,0) node (s1) [block_noborder=0.35\textwidth,right] {%
           \includegraphics[width=\hsize, trim = 1.55cm 1.4cm 0 0, clip] {spectral/figures/FilterResponseMiddleEar.pdf}}
                                node (s2) [right,block_noborder=0.25\textwidth,right=of s1] {%
                                            $N_c=300$ channels, \\
                                            $f_{\text{s}}^{}=\SI{12000}{Hz}$.};
\draw[snakeline]
        (B4.east) -- + (0.7,0) node[block_dash,right] {Text to the left of it here};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Picture is here for changes:
[image: Pic Here for Changes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move the T down, you would obviously need to move the auxiliary coordinates you have defined down. I rewrote the code a little bit though, using just one auxiliary coordinate, and using two `node`s instead of the `quotes` syntax. But that's mostly because I'm more familiar with it, good chance the same thing is possible using `quotes`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}% <-- added for inserting images, had to be before package `tikz`
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% <-- in real document remove option `demo`
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, decorations.pathmorphing,
                positioning, quotes}
\tikzset{
                    every edge quotes/.style = {font=\small, text=black, align=left},% <-- added for writing edge label in more lines
     block/.style = {draw, rounded corners, very thick,
           minimum width=#1, minimum height=2em, inner sep=2.5pt, outer sep=0pt,
           text width =\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
           align=center},
block_dash/.style = {draw, dashed, rounded corners, thin,
            inner sep=1.5pt, minimum size=2em, text=black,
            execute at begin node={\begin{varwidth}{9cm}},
            execute at end node={\end{varwidth}}},
block_noborder/.style = {text width=#1, align=left, % <-- renamed and removed surplus options
            text=black, inner sep=1.5pt},
 connector/.style = {-stealth',very thick},
 snakeline/.style = {decorate,
            decoration={snake, amplitude=.4mm, segment length=1.5mm,
                        pre length=2mm, post length=2mm},
            thick, gray, -stealth'},
              }% end of tikzset

\usepackage{varwidth, mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}% <-- added for correct writing of units

\begin{document}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%scale=0.1,
    auto,
    node distance=15mm and 0mm]
\node (B31) [block=21mm]         {Split this matrix block into two small blocks.};
\node (B32) [block=21mm,
            right=5mm of B31]   {Split this matrix block into two small blocks.};
\path   let \p1 = ($(B31.west)-(B32.east)$),
            \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
        node (B2) [block=\n1,
                   above right=of B31.north west]  {Half}
        node (B1) [block=\n1,
                   above=of B2]   {Gamma}
        node (B4) [block=\n1,%,
         below right=of B31.south west]   {Text here};
%
\draw[connector]    
    ($(B1.north)+(0,1)$) node[left] {$x(n)$} -- (B1)
    (B1) to ["$y^{}_\text{s}$" ', "Something\\ here"]  (B2); 
    \coordinate[below=11mm of B2.south] (B33); % <-- auxiliary coordinates, for orthogonal paths between `box` nodes
    \coordinate[below=4mm of B32.south-|  B4] (B35);
\draw[connector]
        (B2) -- 
        node[right] {Something here}
        node[left] {$y_s$}
        (B33) -| (B31);
\draw[connector]
        (B2) -- (B33) -| (B32);
\draw[connector]
        (B31) edge ["$y^{}_\text{s}$" ', "short\\ text"]    (B31 |- B4.north);
\draw[connector]
        (B32) |- (B35) to ["$y^{}_\text{s}$" ', "Something\\ here"]   (B4);
%
\draw[snakeline]
        (B32.east) -- + (0.7,0) node[block_dash,right] {Text to the left of it here. Text to the left of it here.Text to the left of it here.Text to the left of it here};
\draw[snakeline] % <-- this part of code is rewrite from scratch
        (B1.east) -- + (0.7,0) node (s1) [block_noborder=0.35\textwidth,right] {%
           \includegraphics[width=\hsize, trim = 1.55cm 1.4cm 0 0, clip] {spectral/figures/FilterResponseMiddleEar.pdf}}
                                node (s2) [right,block_noborder=0.25\textwidth,right=of s1] {%
                                            $N_c=300$ channels, \\
                                            $f_{\text{s}}^{}=\SI{12000}{Hz}$.};
\draw[snakeline]
        (B4.east) -- + (0.7,0) node[block_dash,right] {Text to the left of it here};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry wrong picture uploaded as it hadn't been saved. I have updated it to what I want. Just what is in red.

Comment: @JSpen Ah, that's even easier then, see updated answer.

Comment: Okay well now that I have added in all the text on the right that the squigly lines. Most of this is longer than the blocks. All the blocks are set to node distance=15mm. I want to selectively change some blocks to further node distances. Where would I add this in? Of note, I have like 4 blocks below the last block shown here where the overlap occurs. Anyways the text can be rather large that the squigly line points to.

Comment: @JSpen For example `above=25mm of someothernode`?

Comment: Okay, I figured out to use yshift=-2cm which seemed to work. Thanks!